# How to real-time stream from an async iterable to an IPC Streaming format file?

Tags: javascript, apache-arrow

Given an async iterable object that supports the [`for await...of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of), what is the most efficient way to write the elements into an [IPC Streaming format file from Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Columnar.html#ipc-streaming-format)?

Elements are objects following the same schema which contains different data types, for example:

```
[
    {
        id: '747368456',
        product: 'foo',
        price: 732.98,
        created: '2021-05-01T14:00:33.048Z',
    },
    {
        id: '747368457',
        product: 'foo2',
        price: 2.98,
        created: '2021-05-01T14:10:33.023Z',
    }
]
```

Is it possible to do it asynchronously and without waiting for all the JSON objects?

Comment: Just `for await (const event of stream) ipc.write(event)`? Possibly with `await ipc.write(event)` if it's asynchronous?

Comment: @Bergi I think it's needed to use [apache-arrow.RecordBatchWriter](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/js/classes/Arrow_dom.RecordBatchWriter.html) so the events are parsed to IPC format. However, this object doesn't have any `toFile` method or similar.